# Could not `Autowired`, no bean of `SessionFactory` type found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to run test for add data to database using Spring Hibernate. I assigned `@Bean` for function getSessionFactory in `HibernateConfig.java`, but when I call again in DAOImp file, I get error `Could not autowire. No beans of 'SessionFactory' type found.`

## HibernateConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.huyvt.onlineshopping.dto"})
public class HibernateConfig {
    private final static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/onlineshopping?serverTimezone=UTC";
    private final static String DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final static String DATABASE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect";
    private final static String DATABASE_USER = "root";
    private final static String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "";

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USER);
        dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource){
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        sessionFactoryBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", DATABASE_DIALECT);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

## CategoryDAOImp.java

```
@Repository("categoryDAO")
public class CategoryDAOImp implements CategoryDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean add(Category category) {
        try {
            //add category to db
            System.out.println(category.toString());
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(category);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @Autowired tells the application context to inject an instance of SessionFactory here in your DAOImpl. Please enable `<context:component-scan>` in your `applicationContext.xml` so that classes can be scanned for @Controller, @Service, etc. annotations.

Comment: In dispatcher.xml, I added 2 `<context:component-scan>` is controller and daoimp, perhaps missing?

Comment: Also, please provide complete error trace

Comment: in getSessionFactory function, i miss scanPackage method so can not initial SessionFactory for CategoryDAOImpl

Answer (score 0):

In which package is your `HibernateConfig class` found ?

This

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource){
```

is not being executed.

To confirm, you could do a 'System.out.println("XXX")' like so:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource){
    System.out.println("sessionFactory bean is getting created")
    ...
}
```

and check if you can see it in your console when you launch your application.

To ensure that it is being picked up, the easiest way is to ensure that you have a `@ComponentScan` in your root class found here `com.huyvt.onlineshopping`.

> `@ComponentScan` without arguments tells Spring to scan the current
> package and all of its sub-packages.

If you are using Spring Boot, this is automatically added for you when you are using `@SpringBootApplication`.

Also, in your `main` method, you can check your created beans like so:

```
private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    applicationContext = 
      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringComponentScanApp.class);

    for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
        System.out.println(beanName);
    }
}
```